# XCode 4.3 fails to find built app to run

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4.3

Just upgraded from 4.2 to 4.3 and SnowLeopard to Lion. Trying to run an app on the device I get this error:

No such file or directory (/Users/ransom/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NordicSemiDemo-fbdqueftbwgnzeceifltlleucibx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/NordicSemiDemo.app/NordicSemiDemo)

i can verify that the app is at that path, and cd into the bundle and see its contents.

Tried cleaning the build.
The app runs in the simulator.
I am able to run other apps to the same device, using seemingly the same build settings.
There are no hard-coded build paths that I can tell.
I tried manually deleting the build and its directories..

Comment: Why the downvote? I've spent hours trying to figure this out, and searched high and low in stackoverflow! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that restarting the Mac solved the issue.